# Cunningly getting out of an awkward position or situation

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

In Russian we have a term "**Выкрутился из положения**" or just "**Выкрутился**" which means **cunningly getting out of an awkward position or situation**.

> I mean, imaging, you are talking to a writer and you ask him different questions about his book and he tries to answer them but he seems not to know his own book well enough or just doesn't want to answer all those questions so he just says, "You can find all the answers in my book" and so you say this...

What is the English term for it *(a phrase, an idiom or a word)*?

Comment: Check out [*Bre'r Rabbit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%27er_Rabbit).

Comment: @J.R. I'm sorry. What exactly should I check out there?

Comment: The folk tale expresses the same ability to escape a difficult situation. A good English term is _wily_ from the archaic _wile._

Comment: Sounds like "deflecting" to me ... I mean, if he doesn't know his own book and all.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I guess **wily** is a *noun* and not a *verb*? Can you provide a few examples?

Comment: @SovereignSun - You could say, "The professor is a [or _just like_] Bre'r Rabbit." And _wily_ is an [**adjective**](http://www.wordnik.com/words/wily).

Comment: @j.R. I see. What if I wanted a verb or something close to the title of my question, like, say, "**He cunningly got out of the situation**".

Comment: If you wanted a verb, you should have asked for a verb, not a "phrase, idiom, or word"!

Comment: To weasel out of something is another expression. Weasels are regarded as sneaky animals. There are also weasel words, e.g. words that can mean various things. So, "He weaseled out of having to work on Saturday."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wriggle+out+of) (alternative added):

> **wriggle (or wiggle) out of**
>   To extricate oneself from (an undesirable situation or responsibility, for example) by sly or subtle means

[This Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) contains the following translation of the phrase in the question:

> выкрутиться из затруднительного положения [...] ― **to extricate oneself from a difficult situation**; get out of a scrape

---

There are also phrases such as ***give an evasive answer***, ***dodge*** / **sidestep the question**, etc., which might be worth considering when describing the situation you presented.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but I must comment: I like _get out of a scrape_ much better than "extricate oneself from a difficult situation". (I think "extricate oneself" is a fine translation, but a bit too formal for most day-to-day conversation.)

Comment: @J.R. Is "**get out of a scrape**" used frequently and is it a catch phrase?

Comment: _Wriggle out of_ is much more a catch phrase than _get out of a scrape._ _Scrape_ is nicely idiomatic. _Wriggle out of a tight spot_ might be spot on, I'd say, especially since Выкрутился = twist, and _twist_ and _wriggle_ both describe the same physical action.

Comment: @J.R. I agree. What I was trying to indirectly point out is its similarity with the definition of the proposed word (which is why I included it in the first place).

Comment: @SovereignSun - [This](http://postcourier.com.pg/lets-talk-business-2/) was published just yesterday.

Comment: Can I use it like this, "**He quickly wriggled out when I asked him about the book**"?

Comment: @SovereignSun I think that would be acceptable, but I'd stick to the full idiom. He wriggled out of the (embarrassing) situation / tight spot, etc.